# PHPExcel with CodeIgniter merge two different columns to give a result

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working with a spreadsheet where I have column 'G' and 'M' where I have in column 'G' cities names and in 'M' I have the date where determined product was delivered there. I'm working in a system where I need to get the information from the both columns and display in a dashboard like "Cities X Date Delivered". For example, City A have 30 products delivered at May 2th. After I'll build some chart or something. But for now, I need to found a way to merge that information perhaps into an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to worry about what type of product but how many products where delivered on a certain date, you could have an 2D array where the key is the name of the city and the value is an array of dates:

```
// key = City, Value = {date1, date2, ... ,dateN}
$deliveredProducts = array
    (
        "city1" => array("date1", "date2", "date1"),
        "city2" => array("date2", "date3", "date2")
    );

//To get the number of products delivered to city1 on date1:
$tally = array_count_values($deliveredProducts["city1"]);
$count = $tally["date1"];
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Actually yes, it helps a lot! You helped me find the logic to do that! Array inside array. Thank you!